# JavaFX maven plugin and API incompatibility

Tags: java, maven, javafx, maven-plugin

Recently I've upgraded my Java version to 7u40 on my Fedora 19. And after that I've started to get an annoing error during my current JavaFX project running:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.929s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Oct 16 17:36:05 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/155M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:2.0:run (default-cli) on project browser: Execution default-cli of goal com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:2.0:run failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:2.0:run: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession.getRepositorySession()Lorg/sonatype/aether/RepositorySystemSession;
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:2.0
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/home/sk_/.m2/repository/com/zenjava/javafx-maven-plugin/2.0/javafx-maven-plugin-2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/home/sk_/.m2/repository/org/twdata/maven/mojo-executor/2.0/mojo-executor-2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/home/sk_/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-util/1.7/aether-util-1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/home/sk_/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/home/sk_/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/home/sk_/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/home/sk_/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/home/sk_/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.1/plexus-utils-1.5.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/home/sk_/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/1.4.2/sisu-inject-bean-1.4.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/home/sk_/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/2.1.7/sisu-guice-2.1.7-noaop.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/home/sk_/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/2.1.1/plexus-archiver-2.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/home/sk_/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/home/sk_/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.0.3/plexus-io-2.0.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/../lib/ant-javafx.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

Anyone faced that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved with Maven downgrade to 3.0.5

Answer (score 16):

I was able to get around this in maven 3.1.1 by configuring my javafx-maven-plugin as follows (specifying mojo-executor version as 2.1.0)...

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>net.jalbright.scratch.App</mainClass>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.twdata.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mojo-executor</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The javafx-maven-plugin will be updated to use mojo-executor to 2.1.0 in the next version (see: https://github.com/zonski/javafx-maven-plugin/issues/32), so this can be removed once the javafx-maven-plugin gets rev'd.

Comment: I am using maven 3.2.5 and specifying the **mojo-executor version** fixed the problem for me.

Comment: The javafx-maven-plugin since version 8.4.0 (released since today) does not require *mojo-executor* anymore ;) so it should work without workarounds like these. *Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of that plugin*